# .NET ListViemItem background color won't change

Tags: c#, .net, listview, colors

Want to change background color of one of ListViewItem subItems. But nothing happens. Why? Winforms

```
if (tmp.points == 100) {
    //ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem li = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(tmp_item,tmp.verdict);
    //li.BackColor = Color.Green;
    //tmp_item.SubItems.Add(li);
    tmp_item.SubItems.Add(tmp.verdict,Color.Red,Color.Green, new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20) );
} else if (tmp.points == 0) {
    tmp_item.SubItems.Add(tmp.verdict,Color.Black,Color.Red, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20) );
} else {
    tmp_item.SubItems.Add(tmp.verdict,Color.Black,Color.Yellow, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the UseItemStyleForSubItems property of the ListViewItem is true, which overrides this property. Set that property to true and then try this:

```
myListView.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

// Then for the subitems
tmp_item.SubItems.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```